# Python lambda if statement - do you have to have else?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

For example say i have the below list and I want to print out only even #s  - i want to use lambda.
My question is do i need to have a else in the if ?

```
_l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_l2 = list(map(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else "", _l))
```

I dont want to use the else ...

Comment: Why are you asking *us*?  What happened when you tried it?  If you don't *know* whether or not your code works, you don't yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I could do this also

_l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
_l2 = list ( map ( lambda x : x if x%2 == 0 else None, _l))
_l3 = list(filter(None, _l2))
print(_l3)

Comment: Conditional expressions *require* an else. But it sounds like you want to *filter* out odds? Because you can't `filter` with `map`, regardless of if you use a `lambda` or with a conditional expression or not. Functions have to return **something**, so if you `map` you will always get a list with the same amount of elements as your original list.

Comment: So this question seems to be about *`map`*, fundamentally

Answer (score 2):

That's not an `if` <sub>statement anyway</sub>, it's a conditional expression. Python conditional expressions are of the form `z if x else y`, so yes, you do need the `else`.

However, it looks like you're really just trying to filter the list, so if you want an one-liner, use a list comprehension with an `if` fragment:

```
l2 = [x for x in l if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: or since they *insist* on using `lambda`, `filter(lambda x%2 == 0, l)`

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle with list comprehension maybe just use `filter`. Might be easier to grasp if you insist on using `lambda` and want to write functional programming.

```
_l2 = list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0), _l))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys - i can def use list comprehension also can use filter - thats what i did (posted in the comment).

I guess what i was really asking is can i have a if statement in lambda without the else ?

So for the above yes i used filter - fundamentally :

_l = [x for x in range(0,100,1)]

_l2 = list (map ( lambda x:x if x%2 == 0 else None, _l ) )

_l3 = list ( filter (None, _l2) )

But my question is **Do** i need to have the else ?

thanks